# Class containing collection of itself

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

Thank you for checking this post.
I need help defining a class/data structure for following situation.
The app allows user to graphically create e.g. library structure. I.e.
User can create a shelf, which contains some books and it can contain more shelves and so on.
Basically, Shelf class, and then it contains some properties and a collection of Shelf objects. is this legal (object containing collection of itself)?
Will really appreciate if someone can point me right direction on the type of data structure that will work.
[image]

Comment: Custom class that contains a title etc, a list of books and a list of custom class ?

Comment: I think a better question is: Is this the right way to model the data? It is legal to do; it's similar in concept to a dictionary containing another dictionary.

Comment: thanks.. wat will be a good way to model this data?

Comment: Ultimately it depends upon the constraints of your application and what your users want to do, but my intuition tells me that you could create a different class for the top-level shelf, maybe a "Bookcase", which is a collection of shelves, which is a collection of books. At first the distinction might seem meaningless, but it will become useful when you want to add or modify functionality/business rules. Trying building it out in whatever framework you feel fast at and come back and update this or post a new question when you hit a roadblock.

Comment: The easiest way would be to add a collection property to the Shelf object (e.g. `public List<Shelf> Shelves {get; set;}` but I agree with @ryanwebjackson the best way would seem to be to create a BookCase object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this legal (object containing collection of itself)?

Sure. Every tree structure you've ever worked with has a "Node" that itself has a collection of "Node" - A Windows Forms Control has a Controls property that is a collection of Control. XML document object models have the same notion of nodes that have nodes that have nodes...

If it makes sense to you for any one of your Shelves to contain a mix of Books and other Shelves then go for it.. But do consider carefully what benefits it brings you to have a tree of shelves with books potentially spread all throughout it..